# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createFisherFaceRecognizer'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'm using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.2 I work on Windows 64 bit.
I'm working on a face recognition code and I want to use the OpenCV FaceRecognizer

```
recognizer = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
```

but when i run the code i get this error, 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createFisherFaceRecognizer'
I tried also to write it like this 
 `recognizer = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer()`
but still getting the same error

This is the code, the code is part of a kivy code

```
def FaceRecognizer():
    recognizer = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
    recognizer.load('Trainer/Trainer.yml')
    face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    font = cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    while (True):
        retval,image = cam.read() # reading image from cam
        print np.shape(image)
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # converting image to gray image
        faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray_image,1.3,5)
        ''' detectMultiScale, detects objects of different sizes in the input image.
        the detected objects are returned as a list of rectangles
        '''
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
            Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            if(conf<50):
                    Id="Aladdin Hammodi"
            else:
                    Id= "Unknown"
            cv2.cv.PutText(cv2.cv.fromarray(im),str(Id), (x,y+h),font, 255)
        cv2.imshow('frame',image)
        if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    output = "Recognition is done"
    return output
```

Comment: Give us the complete code please, mayve you imported it with something like `from cv2 import face`

Comment: I tried from cv2 import face and I got this error, 
 ImportError: cannot import name face

Comment: No, copy/paste you complete code please. We can not do anything here

Comment: are you sure that opencv is built with the required module?

Comment: I've added it to the question above

Comment: @HåkenLid http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html?highlight=fisherfacerecognizer

Comment: That's part of the optional `contrib` module. It might not be included by default in your cv2 installation. "The module contains some recently added functionality that has not been stabilized, or functionality that is considered optional."

Comment: @HåkenLid how could I add this? Do you know if this gonna work on Kivy?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Windows to help you with that. There might exist a prebuilt cv2-contrib package for Windows in Anaconda or Pypi

Comment: @HåkenLid ok thanks, I will try to download the cv2-contrib

Comment: @Arount Did you find out what might be the problem here?

Comment: no, is this the **complete** code ? I'm not sure, because it miss `import` part, the one I want you to paste from the begining.

Comment: Import cv2     import numpy as np